# Pass variables from Presentation Layer to Logic Layer

Tags: java, design-patterns, n-tier-architecture

I am stuck when I try to make the Logic Layer update the Presentation Layer since I have initialized GUI variables in the Presentation Layer. Still, after that, I couldn't find a way to reach those variables from the Logic Layer. I don't believe that I should make all variables public to reach them.

I have an example here:

- Logic Layer method that updates multiChoicePanel

  ```
  public void clearDisplay() {
            if (currentlyDisplayedQuestion.getQuestionType() == QuestionType.MULTI_CHOICE) {
                multiChoicePanel.clearDisplay();
            } 
           else
            ...
        };
  ```
- Presentation Layer where i have declared multiChoicePanel

  ```
    private JQEMultiChoiceQuestionScreen multiChoicePanel;
  ```

So the question here is how to pass multiChoicePanel to Logic Layer?

Comment: You shouldn't! Just pass the necessary information to the logic layer

Comment: So, clearDisplay() method should be in the Presentation Layer instead of the Logic Layer?

Comment: Yes. For sure! Everything that has to do with the UI belongs to the presentation layer.

Comment: Alright, can we say the Logic Layer is responsible for methods that need to use Data Layer and Presentation Layer together?

Comment: The logic is where you implement the business logic and access the data layer. The logic layer is exposing their functionality through methods but does not access the UI layer

Comment: Now it makes sense, thank you for the help

Comment: If you have arrived at a solution, please post and accept an Answer to your own Question so this page can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question by moveing clearDisplay() in the Presentation Layer and make the Logic Layer expose its functionality through methods.